# editing a CSL style to add the report number to report types

Tags: report, csl

Similarly to what attempted by other users here, I am trying to adapt a CSL style file to specify the report number for citations of (scientific,technical) reports. 
The style that I am attempting to modify (and perhaps suggesting updating in compliance with the journal's manuscript preparation guides) is that used in the scientific journal Physics in Medicine and Biology (Institute of Physics) and that is based on the Harvard style:
http://www.zotero.org/styles/physics-in-medicine-and-biology

Using the online code editor http://editor.citationstyles.org/codeEditor/ I have peeked into a CSL file that does format -in a bibliography- report numbers, such as the vancouver-author-date.csl style.

It appears that the macro involved is `report-details` so I have accordingly attempted this minor addition to the physics-in-medicine-and-biology style file, which I have temporarily renamed (and changed its id) to physics-in-medicine-and-biology-with-report.

```
[...]
</info>
  <bibliography>
      <layout>
      <macro name="report-details">
          <choose>
            <if type="report techreport" match="any">
              <text variable="number" prefix="Report " font-style="roman"/>
            </if>
          </choose>
        </macro>
    </layout>
    </bibliography>
</style>
```

Upon importing into Papers for Mac (v3.4.1) and selecting this custom citation style, the formatting result is still (as for the unchanged physics-in-medicine-and-biology style):

Andreo P, Burns D T, Hohlfeld K, Huq M, Kanai T, Laitano R F, Smyth V and Vynckier S 2000 *Absorbed Dose Determination in External Beam Radiotherapy, An International Code of Practice for Dosimetry Based on Standards of Absorbed Dose to Water* (Vienna: International Atomic Energy Agency)

as opposed to the desired

Andreo P, Burns D T, Hohlfeld K, Huq M, Kanai T, Laitano R F, Smyth V and Vynckier S 2000 *Absorbed Dose Determination in External Beam Radiotherapy, An International Code of Practice for Dosimetry Based on Standards of Absorbed Dose to Water* Report 398 (Vienna: International Atomic Energy Agency)

What am I missing? Just as a counter check, here is the record exported as BibTeX record, showing the non-null `number` field:

```
@techreport{Andreo:2000vw,
author = {Andreo, Pedro and Burns, David T and Hohlfeld, K and Huq, MS and     Kanai, T and Laitano, Raffaele Fedele and Smyth, Vere and Vynckier, S},
title = {{\emph{Absorbed Dose Determination in External Beam Radiotherapy, An International Code of Practice for Dosimetry Based on Standards of Absorbed Dose to Water}}},
institution = {International Atomic Energy Agency},
year = {2000},
number = {398},
address = {Vienna}
}
```

Thank you for any hints
Yours, Massimo P.

Comment: According to http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#appendix-ii-terms there is no such a type like _tech-report_, so the following was used as update to the above: `<if type="report">`

Comment: This issue was further discussed on GitHub, in citation-style-languages at pull #1775.